# Ignore SSL Warning in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, ssl

Our service provider is blocking the domain of website i want to scrape
But can be still accessed by using the domain IP Public
The problem is the website show SSL Error when accessed using IP Public
So i can't use the assets url inside React Native App
Example Code:

```
<Image
 source={{
    uri: 'https://45.134.21.182/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/RYMX2wcKCBAr24UyPD7xwmjaTn-170x255.jpg',
 }}
 style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
```

The result of the block of code isn't showing anything because of the SSL Error of the website
How can i ignore SSL Error/Warning in my React Native App for access assets using IP Public Address?

[SSL Warning of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPFpF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The ISP is blocking it via DNS. The simplest solution is to just use another DNS service such as the one provided by Google at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  Just configure your operating system to use those two ip addresses as your DNS servers.

Alternatively, you can use a hosts file to override any DNS.  On Windows, this file is is c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt.  On Mac/Linux it's in /etc/hosts.  Just update these files to add a DNS entry for your website.

Answer (score -1):

In the above case it is mandatory to have an ssl.

On the basis of the middle ware like NGINX or Apache or TomCAT etc., Depending upon your middleware look for a clean ssl implementation in the respective platform.

Use letsencrypt.com for getting a free open source ssl.

Patch the certificate with your middleware.

Also Buy a free domain with any free extension like .cc

Goodluck

Comment: But it's not my website, i only want to scrap data from the website, i can't register SSL to the website